# How do you create a Swift animation class that flips two images

Tags: ios, animation, swift

I'm spending my turkey day trying to construct a flip animation class that I have been struggling with for weeks.

The goal is this:

Flip two images repeatedly, quickly at first, then slow down and stop, landing on one of the two images that was chosen before the animation began.

Right now both images are in a container view, in a storyboard. Ive tried using `transitionFromView transitionFlipFromTop` and I think that could work, but at the time I was unable to get it to repeat.

I am in the process of reading the View Programming Guide, but its tough to connect the dots between it, and swift. Being new to programming in general does not help.

Here is where I'm at: I'm now using a `CATransform` to scale an image from zero height, to full height. Im thinking that if I can somehow chain two animations, the first one showing the first image scaling up, then back down to zero, then animate the second image doing the same thing, that should give me the first part. Then if I could somehow get those two animations to repeat, quickly at first, then slow down and stop.

It seems I need to know how to nest multiple animations, and then be able to apply an animation curve to the nested animation.

I planned on solving the part about landing on a particular image by having two of these nested animations, one of them would have an odd number of flips, the other an even number of flips. Depending on the desired final image, the appropriate animation gets called.

Right now, my current code is able to repeatedly scale an image from zero to full, a set number of times:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

let FlipAnimatorStartTransform:CATransform3D = {

    let rotationDegrees: CGFloat = -15.0
    let rotationRadians: CGFloat = rotationDegrees * (CGFloat(M_PI)/180.0)
    let offset = CGPointMake(-20, -20)
    var startTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
    startTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 0),
        1, 0, 1);

    return startTransform
    }()

class FlipAnimator {
    class func animate(view: UIView) {

        let viewOne = view
        let viewTwo = view

        viewOne.layer.transform = FlipAnimatorStartTransform
        viewTwo.layer.transform = FlipAnimatorStartTransform

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(7)

            viewOne.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

        },nil)
    }
}
```

Im going to keep chipping away at it. Any help, or ideas, or hints about a better way to go about it would be amazing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this function to rotate image horizontally and to change the image during the transition.

```
private func flipImageView(imageView: UIImageView, toImage: UIImage, duration: NSTimeInterval, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0)
{
    let t = duration / 2

    UIView.animateWithDuration(t, delay: delay, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

        // Rotate view by 90 degrees
        let p = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90)), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        imageView.layer.transform = p

    }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in

        // New image
        imageView.image = toImage

        // Rotate view to initial position
        // We have to start from 270 degrees otherwise the image will be flipped (mirrored) around Y axis
        let p = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(270)), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        imageView.layer.transform = p

        UIView.animateWithDuration(t, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            // Back to initial position
            let p = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(0)), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            imageView.layer.transform = p

        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
        })
    })
}
```

Don't forget to import GLKit.

Answer (score 1):

This flip animation swift code appears little better:

```
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.startProgress = 0;
        transition.endProgress = 1.0;
        transition.type = "flip";
        transition.subtype = "fromRight";
        transition.duration = 0.9;
        transition.repeatCount = 2;
        self.cardView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: " ")
```

Other option is

```
@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
var back: UIImageView!
var front: UIImageView!
self.front = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "heads.png"))
self.back = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "tails.png"))
self.cardView.addSubview(self.back)
UIView.transitionFromView(self.back, toView: self.front, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight , completion: nil)
```

Please check [link](http://www.codingricky.com/flipping-cards-with-swift-and-uikit/)

Comment: Thanks :)
What I need exactly

Answer (score 0):

> It seems I need to know how to nest multiple animations, and then be able to apply an animation curve to the nested animation.

I don't think so. I don't think you want/need to *nest* anything. You are not *repeating* an animation in this story; you are doing *different* animations each time (because the durations are to differ). This is a sequence of animations. So I think what you need to know is how to do either a *keyframe* animation or a *grouped* animation. That way you can predefine a series of animations, each one lasting a certain predefined duration, each one starting after the preceding durations are over.

And for that, I think you'll be happiest at the Core Animation level. (You can't make a grouped animation at the UIView animation level anyway.)

Comment: See, for instance, my example code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p148layerAnimation/ch17p490layerAnimation/ViewController.swift Case 9 does something rather similar to what you are after: it waggles a compass arrow back and forth closer and closer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointers Matt. Ill take a look and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Wow.. Judging from the code you linked to, it seems that I have bitten off way more than I can chew at the moment. Ill probably just aim for getting it the view to flip a few times and stop on the correct one for now.

Comment: I don't agree at all. This is easy, basic, and important stuff. If you don't mind reading Objective-C code from a couple of iOS revs back, the freebie version of my book teaches you everything you need to know: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_core_animation

Comment: Also, iOS now lets you do keyframe animations as a UIView animation, as I demonstrate here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch04p135keyFrameViewAnimation/keyFrameViewAnimation/ViewController.swift That sort of thing _might_ be all you need. Try it!

Comment: The main point I'm making is that this was never a repeated animation, because the conditions are changing on each animation. You need to break out of that limited mindset and into the wonderful _real_ world of all that animation can do for you.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Ill check out your books, and give it a shot. Just a bit overwhelming trying to learn everything at once. I have very little programming experience to begin with, and then I'm trying to learn in a language with few examples. So trying to take an example from Objective-C and getting it to work in Swift, when I don't know the correct syntax to begin with is tough.

Comment: The current edition is in Swift, of course. However, note that knowing how to read Objective-C and mentally translate it to Swift should be part of your skillset in any case, since Objective-C is everywhere and always will be. After all, the APIs are all really Objective-C; you can't understand _any_ method/function call thru the APIs unless you know C and Objective-C.

Comment: So you would recommend "iOS 7 Programming Fundamentals" ?
Right now I am a third of the way through this course, and thought I got smart, and started trying to make a "Simple" app in Swift.
[link](https://www.udemy.com/complete-ios-developer-course/#/)

Comment: I don't recommend anything. What do you want to do? If you just want to learn Objective-C, use the freebie online version of my book! Or any other resource you like, including the documentation, which is excellent.

Comment: Im looking for explanations from the ground up. When I watch WWDC videos, they make references to all sorts of things that everyone seems to have basic knowledge of, yet seems just out of reach for me.
Most Apple documentation assumes you already know quite a bit it seems.

Comment: WWDC videos are definitely not "from the ground up"!

Comment: I may spend some time with you in your books. The intro to "Programming IOS 6 is fairly compelling.